# Function Call in Jquery

Tags: jquery, function, call

I saw a jquery function call in one of the website where the function is called like

```
var exampleFunction = function() {
    console.log ( " running " );
}

$(exampleFunction);
```

And it is called like $(exampleFunction); Is this fine to use this ? Its working though but i have not seen this type of coding style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$(function)` is short for `$(document).ready(function)`. So `exampleFunction` will be called when the dom is loaded

See http://api.jquery.com/ready/